# liferay velocity portlets instead of jsp

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, velocity, liferay-6.2

I have created liferay theme using velocity and portlets using jsp. Can anyone please tell me whether we can create portlets using velocity instead of jsp's. I google for some velocity portlets in liferay but could'nt find any. Also I would like to know whther there is any drwbacks using velocity instead of jsp for liferay portlets

Comment: Funny. A simple [google search](https://www.google.de/search?q=velocityportlet) shows enough helpful results. At least for me. What about [this one](https://dotcms.com/docs/latest/creating-portlets)?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot(till my best knowledge) use velocity for portlet development but velocity templates may be used in portlets.

Here is some part of blog

By default, the portlet we create is MVC portlet and use default MVCPortlet class. Now do the following:

1. At First create a custom class and it should inherit com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet class.
2. We have to override the doView method where we will write our code for Velocity Engine initialization...
   [continue..](http://www.apoorvaprakash.in/2012/04/using-velocity-templates-in-portlets.html)

However it is quite older post, for Liferay 6.2, but you can give it a try.